# How can you find if a string in python approximately contains another string?

Tags: python

Suppose I want to check if a string has `'pizza'` in it. But my user accidentally typed `'I want piztza'` by accident (a simple typo). Is there a way to check if the user input approximately contains `'pizza'`? Perhaps if only off by one letter.

Comment: Check out the `fuzzywuzzy` package.

Comment: `from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz` then `fuzz.partial_ratio("I want piztza", "pizza")` gives 80, whereas `fuzz.partial_ratio("I want fish", "pizza")` gives 22. You would need to decide on an appropriate cutoff value.

Answer (score 1):

Try using fuzzywuzzy from PyPI: https://pypi.org/project/fuzzywuzzy/. I am not very experienced with it, but the website should help.

Comment: You would probably use `fuzz.partial_ratio`. See my comments under the question for an example.

Comment: You should just post your answer as an answer to the question instead of a comment.

Comment: The culture here is definitely that answers need to be somewhat more developed than what gets posted as comments. Mine was somewhat borderline, but I am happy to just leave it as a comment, especially in view of other answers that have since appeared. Yours, if you don't mind me saying, fits firmly into the category of what most people would post as a comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score 1):

`fuzzywuzzy` would be one way to do this. `fuzzywuzzy` library compares the similarity between two strings. The *Jaccard distance* is one method that `fuzzywuzzy` uses. The *Jaccard distance* - measure  any two sets.

This is what the formula looks like :

[image]

Here is a visual representation of the formula:

[image]

Here is how you could implement it:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
similarity = fuzz.ratio("hello","world") # 0%
```

This will give you a ratio of how similar the words are.
Here is another example:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
similarity = fuzz.ratio("Austria","Australia") # Will give you 88%
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use fuzzywuzzy package

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

q1 = input("type 'pizza': ")
compare = fuzz.ratio(q1, 'pizza')
if compare > 90:
    print("you type pizza")
else:
    print("you didn't type 'pizza'")
```

check [his documentation](https://pypi.org/project/fuzzywuzzy/) for more uses, this is only a simple code.

Comment: Wow thanks so much everyone! I checked out fuzzywuzzy but it seemed like it was more useful for directly comparing two similar strings and not for finding strings in strings. I think I will use something similar to what user13914826 posted. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sentence = "I want piztza"
Word = "pizza"
Same = False
for Sen_Word in Sentence.lower().split(" "):
    if Sen_Word == Word:
        Same = True
    elif len(Sen_Word) == len(Word)+1:
        Left_Count=0
        Right_Count=0
        for i, x in zip(Sen_Word, Word):
            if i == x:
                Left_Count += 1
            else:
                break
        Letters_Left = min(len(Sen_Word), len(Word))-Left_Count
        for i, x in zip(Sen_Word[::-1], Word[::-1]):
            if Letters_Left - Right_Count > 0 and i == x:
                Right_Count += 1
            else:
                break
        if Left_Count + Right_Count == len(Word):
            Same = True
print(Same)
```

or a shorter code:

```
Sentence = "I like piztza"
Word = "pizza"
Same = False
for Sen_Word in Sentence.split(" "):
    if Sen_Word == Word: Same = True
    elif len(Sen_Word) == len(Word)+1:
        Left_Count=Right_Count=0
        for i, x in zip(Sen_Word, Word):
            if i == x: Left_Count += 1
            else: break
        Letters_Left = min(len(Sen_Word), len(Word))-Left_Count
        for i, x in zip(Sen_Word[::-1], Word[::-1]):
            if Letters_Left - Right_Count > 0 and i == x: Right_Count += 1
            else: break
        if Left_Count + Right_Count == len(Word): Same = True
print(Same)
```